# React Re render issue from Child to parent Component

Tags: reactjs, tooltip, render, antd, react-props

i have created a separate file for table id copy to clipboard and tooltip,  i am facing issue when hovering the icon when i copied more than one the previous one is not changing to default in this  order id first i copied if i click second id it should change copied and first back to copy tooltip . parent component is not rendering the one

i have multiple list component each components consist of table's each table has id's for that if i used locally state and onclick function it working fine no problem if i have two or three id's i want declare separate state and click function so that i have create separate component as child for common use for whole project if i declare the states and onclick function in parent then no use of child component Right

Parent Component
Table Array.map

```
<td>
<CopyID copyText={list?.orderId} rowIndex={i}/> 
</td>
```

Child Component

```
import { Tooltip } from 'antd';
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import CopyToClipboard from 'react-copy-to-clipboard';
export const CopyID = ({copyText,rowIndex}) => {
const [triggeredIndex, setTriggeredIndex] = useState(null);
const orderIdCopy = (i) => {
    setTriggeredIndex(i);
};


return (
    <CopyToClipboard text={copyText || ' '} onCopy={() => orderIdCopy(rowIndex)}>
        <Tooltip
            overlayClassName='custom-tooltip-style'
            title={triggeredIndex === rowIndex ? 'Copied' : 'Copy'}
            color={triggeredIndex === rowIndex ? '#018c5c' : 'geekblue'}>
            <i
              key={rowIndex}
                className='bx bx-copy me-2 align-middle fs-6 '
                style={{
                    cursor: 'pointer'
                }}></i>
        </Tooltip>
    </CopyToClipboard>
);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue you're facing arises because each CopyID component maintains its own `triggeredIndex` state, which tracks whether its tooltip should display "Copied" or "Copy".

To solve this, you need a way to globally track the last copied ID across all CopyID components.

```
const ParentComponent = ({ dataList }) => {
  const [lastCopiedIndex, setLastCopiedIndex] = useState(null);

  const handleCopy = (index) => {
    setLastCopiedIndex(index);
  };
}
```

Child

```
export const CopyID = ({ copyText, rowIndex, onCopy, isLastCopied }) => {}
```

State should handled like this.

Comment: Hi i have multiple list component each components consist of table's each table has id's for that if i used locally state and onclick function it working fine no problem if i have two or three id's i want declare separate state and click function so that i have create separate component as child  for common use for whole project if i declare the states and onclick function in parent then no use of child component Right ?

Comment: Hi you can use dictionary in that case, update this question or add new question. i will add basic code